# Android:Display images in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

Hi i am making an app in which i have to use scroll with gridview . I want to set limit of scroll to six images i.e. when i scroll i should get six images in gridview.But i am getting **Array Index Out of Bound on Scroll**. My code is as follows:

```
public class ListMobileActivity extends Activity {

        public static int items=14;
        private boolean loadingMore=false;
        public static ArrayList<String> url;
        public static ArrayList<String> name;
        NewSaxParserActivity activity;
        String[] values;
        MobileArrayAdapter adapter;
        GridView gridview;
        int x=0;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            System.out.println("welcome to gridview");
            setContentView(R.layout.categorygridview);
            savedInstanceState=this.getIntent().getExtras();
            String string=String.valueOf(savedInstanceState.getInt("id"));
            String string1=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            String string2=getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");

            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.catName);
            textView.setText(string2);
            gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridfour);


         activity=new NewSaxParserActivity();
         activity.display(string1,string);


            url=new ArrayList<String>();
            name=new ArrayList<String>();
            name=activity.name;*/
            adapter=new MobileArrayAdapter(ListMobileActivity.this,url,name);
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            gridview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;             
                    System.out.println("lastinscreen::::"+lastInScreen);
                    if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){                 
                        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                        thread.start();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }
            });
             Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                thread.start();
        }

    private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {           
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int x=0;
                loadingMore = true;

                url = new ArrayList<String>();
                name = new ArrayList<String>();
                 System.out.println("url1 size :"+activity.url1.size());
                try { Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                for (int i = 0; i < items
                        ; i++) {
                    System.out.println("x :"+x);
                    url.add(activity.url1.get(x).toString()); 
                    name.add(activity.name.get(x).toString()); 
                    x=x+1;
                    }

                 runOnUiThread(returnRes);

            }
        };  
        private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                if(url != null && url.size() > 0){
                    System.out.println("size :"+url.size());
                    System.out.println("size :"+name.size());
                    for(int i=0;i<url.size();i++)
                    {System.out.println("url :"+url.get(i));
                    System.out.println("name :"+name.get(i));
                        adapter.add(url.get(i));
                        adapter.add(name.get(i));
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("size :"+url.size());
                System.out.println("size :"+name.size());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                e.getMessage();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loadingMore = false;
            }
        };

    }
```

Above is my main activity and below is my adapter

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] values1;
    String[] name1;
    Activity activity;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;


    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values, ArrayList<String> name) {
        super(context, R.layout.main, values);
        this.context=context;
        values1=new String[values.size()];
        name1=new String[name.size()];
        Object []arr={"hello"};
        Object []arr1={"hello"};
        arr=values.toArray(arr);
        arr1=name.toArray(arr1);
        activity=(Activity)this.getContext();;
        for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
        {
            values1[i]=arr[i].toString();
            name1[i]=arr1[i].toString();
        }
        this.activity=(Activity)this.getContext();
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        System.out.println("getView");
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.label);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        System.out.println("position :"+position);
        System.out.println("name :"+name1.length);
        System.out.println("values :"+values1.length);
        System.out.println("name on position :"+name1[position]);
        holder.text.setText(name1[position]);
        holder.image.setTag(values1[position]);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(values1[position], activity, holder.image);
        return vi;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }
    *@Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public int getPosition(String item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }

}
```

and following is the exception:

```
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.trigma.pp.MobileArrayAdapter.getView(MobileArrayAdapter.java:77)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:932)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-11 10:15:22.013: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

"String string=String.valueOf(savedInstanceState.getInt("id"));"

"getIntent" not "getInt"?

Answer (score 0):

I see following problem in your source code

```
@Override
    public String getItem(int position)
    {
        return super.getItem(position);

    }
```

Change it to

```
@Override
        public String getItem(int position)
        {
            return name1[position]; 
            or
            return values1[position];

        }
```

and

```
@Override
    public int getPosition(String item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }
```

You will also need to change this to return position of item.